# Suggested startup tasks for access split DB (AutoExec)

Tags: vba, ms-access, frontend, ms-access-2016, autoexec

I am working on a MS Access split database and I read in many places to create AutoExec macro to automate a few startup tasks like securing front end (hide ribbon etc.). I am learning as I am going through the project so I am fairly a newbie to access programming.

Can anyone list, like a few "good practice" startup tasks that can be added to the front end and if possible with sample codes/links to sites.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use macros incl. AutoExec as little as possible, as these are hard to debug and document.

Best practice is to specify in *Settings* the form to open at launch, then let this run the startup tasks you need.